# Windows 7 phone cannot display locally stored HTML file in browser

Tags: windows-phone-7, browser

I'm using the embedded web browser, and it (the browser) works fine.  Can I display a locally stored HTML file in it? The file is in folder 'html'.  I am trying it but it does not work - says it cannot find the web page.

My code:

```
<phone:WebBrowser Name="webBrowser1" Height="467" Source="/html/test.html"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

To display static content in a browser control, you can "*use a WebBrowser control to display static web content that an application has saved into isolated storage using the SaveToString() method*".

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431811(v=vs.92).aspx

Hope this helps you.